# Использовать С++ код в С# в VS2017

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017

У меня есть исходный код написанный на с++. У меня есть интерфейс написанный на с#. Как объединить?
ПРИМЕР:

```
//myCPPcode.cpp
int summ(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Что я должен сделать, что бы мог использовать эту ф-цию в коде C#?

Comment: Выучить C# и переписать код на него. Он там, как ни странно, будет выглядеть почти точно так же.

Comment: Как вариант скомпилировать библиотеку.......

Comment: Читайте что такое Dynamic/Static Library, как сделать extern, как скомпилировать библиотеку, как подключить библиотеку к проекту C#, как объявить точки входа (extern методы, искомые в библиотеке), как связать искомые методы в подключенной библиотеке, а далее - всё просто, вызывайте ваш код в шарпе, выглядить вызов будет, как ни странно, примерно так: int result = summ(2,5);